# Android - Is there a way to achieve the same result without webView?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the "html-out" of a webpage after it's loaded.
Here is the code I'm using now:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    final WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browser);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "HtmlViewer");

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                    "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
        }
    });

    webview.loadUrl("http://android-in-action.com/index.php?post/" +
            "Common-errors-and-bugs-and-how-to-solve-avoid-them");
}

class MyJavaScriptInterface {

    private Context ctx;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public void showHTML(String html) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).setTitle("HTML").setMessage(html)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null).setCancelable(false).create().show();
    }

}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same without using WebView? I don't want to use any views at all, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to achieve the same without using WebView?

Use an HTTP API to perform the HTTP `GET` request. For example, `HttpUrlConnection` has been around for 15 years or so. Or, if you prefer something more modern, use [the OkHttp library](https://github.com/square/okhttp):

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String urlString = "http://android-in-action.com/index.php?post/Common-errors-and-bugs-and-how-to-solve-avoid-them";
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(urlString).build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

String html = response.body().string();
```

That code, based on [an OkHttp published recipe](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#user-content-synchronous-get), should be called on a background thread, or use their asynchronous API options.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not working for me. It returns the regular html, exactly like IOUtils.toString(URI.create("...")) does. The code I wrote returns a different string

Comment: @SaharAvr: "The code I wrote returns a different string" -- then you are going to need to determine what exactly is different and what caused it to be different.

Comment: I'm trying to extract the url of one button inside a webpage. In the source code the link is disguised inside a script, however if I hover my mouse on the button- the url appears. The code I used returns an html that includes the url of the button.

Comment: @SaharAvr: Well, that means that you need a piece of software that can interpret HTML and embedded JavaScript that manipulates that HTML. That basically means that you need a Web browser. `WebView` is going to be your simplest option by far.

Comment: There is no way whatsoever to retrieve that inner html without a webview? This is causing my app to be much slower...
If no, can you suggest a way to achieve it faster than the code in my post?

Comment: @SaharAvr: "There is no way whatsoever to retrieve that inner html without a webview?" -- you wrote earlier that "the link is disguised inside a script". The only way to get that script to run, and run successfully, is to have the Web page be interpreted by a browser-style rendering engine. You are certainly welcome to come up with some other algorithm to "retrieve that inner html", but that algorithm will break when the site owner (apparently, somebody other than you) changes their site.

Comment: @SaharAvr: A better approach would be for you to talk to the maintainers of the site, explain what your app is and how it would benefit their site, and determine a better way for you to work with their site data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85158/discussion-between-sahar-avr-and-commonsware).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't talk to the site owners.
Maybe I can try speeding the page-load. Can you describe to me how to make the webView not load images?